# Testing udp performance

Tags: c++, c, performance, sockets, udp

I have Intel Galileo Board ("low" performance pc) and PC ("fast" performance) linked with Ethernet.
I wrote UDP server on Galileo and UDP client on PC. Server receives udp packets and accumulates their amount in variable count.
Part of code:

```
static void recvfrom_int(int);
static long count;
unsigned long long received = 0;     

static void recvfrom_int(int signo) {
    printf("\nreceived %d datagrams\n", count);
    printf("\nreceived bytes: %d\n", received);
    exit(0);
} 

int main () {  
    signal(SIGINT, recvfrom_int);        
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;    
    char mesg[MAXLINE];        
    ...
    ...
    sockfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); 
    ...
    ...
    count = 0;     
    for ( ; ; ) {    
        received += recvfrom(sockfd, mesg, MAXLINE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, &len);
        count++;        
    }        
}
```

And i have client code, which send NDG(50000) datagrams, each datagram has size DGLEN.
Part of client:

```
#define MAXLINE 90000
#define NDG 50000 /* datagrams to send */    
#define DGLEN 3100 /* each datagram size */

int main () {
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    char sendline[MAXLINE];   
    int i;
    int n = 0;
    ...
    ...
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    ...
    //SENDING DATAGRAMS
    for (i = 0; i < NDG; i++) {
        n = write(sockfd, sendline, DGLEN);
    }

}
```

Similar code can be seen Stevens book, chapter 8.13.
[http://www.amazon.com/UNIX-Network-Programming-Richard-Stevens/dp/0139498761](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0139498761)

My results:

```
DGLEN (DATAGRAM SIZE in bytes)     COUNT (amount of datagrams, RECEIVED ON SERVER)
   10                                 67
   50                                 67
   100                                67
   200                                68
   300                                68
   400                                69
   500                                94
   600                              1067
   700                             12799  
   800                             25884
   900                             35542
  1000                             49957
  1200                        near 50000
  1300                        near 50000
  1400                        near 50000
  1472                             48338
  1473                                71
```

I don't undertstand what it means.
I think, that small count with DGLEN = 1473, it is because ethernet MTU = 1500, and maximum size of datagram without fragmentation is 1472 (1500 Ethernet MTU - 20 for IP header without options - 8 UDP header = 1472). With size 1473 we obtain fragmentation, which leads to small count of received datagrams on server (if i understand correctly, maybee speed of fragmentation on PC more than on Galileo). 
And I don't understand, why count = 67 with DGLEN = 10/50/100/.../500 and why it
then begins to rise (count = 12799 DGLEN = 700, count = 49957 DGLEN = 1000, etc.)

Rest of data:

```
1600 70
2000 72
2100 1125
2200 6021
2300 10404
2500 20370
2800 30046
2900 37729
2944 39052
2950 39610
2952 42907
2953 15540
3000 15587
3100 21373
```

Comment: Why count = 67?  Probably related to minimum ethernet packet size.  from WireShark: "Ethernet packets with less than the minimum 64 bytes for an Ethernet packet (header + user data + FCS) are padded to 64 bytes, which means that if there's less than 64-(14+4) = 46 bytes of user data, extra padding data is added to the packet."

Comment: Maybee when DGLEN = 10 bytes, padding begins to be applied and this leads to 67 datagrams on receive side? I mean this padding fast on fast PC (client UDP), and slow on Galileo(server UDP).. But what about another result data..